# Intellij detects removed sdk/jdk. How to update intellij Cache?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-14

I added Java 14 SDK in Intellij then I removed it. I even checked the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder, the SDK is not there but still IntelliJ list out Java 14 as detected SDK.

Comment: Try the **File | Invalidate Caches & Restart** menu option.

Comment: how did you add it and then how did you remove it? what version of IntelliJ? possible to share pre and post screenshots?

Comment: I added JDK using IntelliJ only and removed it from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines location using the IDE. Version: 2020.1.2(Ultimate)

Comment: Try to remove it from IDE (Project Structure | SDKs | select SDK | click `-`): https://i.imgur.com/DHfFuJG.png